# Dialogflow webhook not working with django

Tags: django, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, ngrok

My Dialogflow webhook was working completely fine till yesterday but it is suddenly not connecting to the webhook today. Although I've made no changes in the code. I'm getting the following fulfillment status:

```
Webhook call failed. Error: NOT_FOUND, State: URL_ERROR, Reason: ERROR_NOT_FOUND, HTTP status code: 404.
```

Please note the following points:

1. Fulfillment URL is written in the correct format (with HTTPS protocol).
2. My Django server is running fine and it is also receiving requests when instigated from the browser. (Just not receiving requests from Dialogflow)
3. Suddenly, none of my Dialogflow agents (previously built and working fine) are sending requests to Django/Flask server.

I've checked multiple things like trying from different Dialogflow accounts and different browsers but I can conclude that the issue is with the Dialogflow webhook/Fulfillment.

Please, help me with the solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: These post may help you [post1](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/242) , [post2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#response_format)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Thank you for your quick response. But I've already checked those but the issue is still not resolved.

Comment: The error was solved after a day without doing anything. It seems that the error was with the Dialogflow webhook. (I wasn't able to figure out what was wrong.)
If anyone finds out the reason, please let me know.

Comment: It's weird that it work properly without doing anything. I check [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) and found nothing that might have cause an issue. I think it might have been on your network provider side that interrupt the service for a brief time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad that you were able to solve your issue somehow. I will leave this complementary recommendations as a community wiki answer to help community with this kind of issues and for visibility. Please feel free to edit this answer to fit your scope.

Recommendations when dealing with webhook errors:

- Check your webhook links, status of the deployment services.
- Check your dialog errors details on your logs, you can see the documentation to activate logging for dialogflow by visiting this [page](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/logging).
- Check the status of [google cloud service](https://status.cloud.google.com/).
- Check webhook documention about [errors](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#errors).
- You can write code to directly interact with dialogflow API and [detect the intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api#detect_intent) and check the status of the API.
- You can also rise your issue or check similar issues on the main [dialogflow for nodejs github project page](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow).
- For information about libraries, rest API, RPC API you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference) to the official documentation.
- If you keep getting the error you might be dealing with a bug, in those cases you can create [bug request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=501190). For more details about dialogflow issue tracker check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports).